# its not working...not found is the answer for everything

Tags: python-3.x

```
num_array = list( )
num =int(input("Enter how many elements you want:"))
print ('Enter numbers in array: ')
for i in range(int(num)):
    n = input("num :")
    num_array.append(int(n))
print ('LIST: ',num_array)
key=int(input ('enter element to be searched:'))
if key==num_array[i]:
    print('element found')
else:
    print("not found")
```

its all about simple linear search in python i have used pseudo code of C and implemented it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xwzi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just forgot to iterate through the loop while checking.

```
key=int(input ('enter element to be searched:'))
found = False;
for num in num_array:
    if key==num:
        print('element found')
        found = True;
if(found==False)
    print("not found")
```